# Limitations of an Eruv

Tags: shabbat, eruv-chatzerot

Are there any limitations to what you can carry or where you can carry within an eruv on Shabbat?

Comment: Could you please [edit] in some information about what's motivating this question?

Comment: This is more of a general Eruv question, than a specifically motivated question. Can I carry anything I want, to anywhere I want within an eruv (as long as it's not mukzah)? Or are there things and places that an Eruv doesn't cover? I think Naftali answered my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anything that would be **useful for use on shabbos** you can carry within an eruv (if you follow the local eruv)

The [Greater Boston Eruv Corporation](http://www.bostoneruv.org/)'s "[Halakhot of Eruv](http://www.bostoneruv.org/halachot.htm)" page has a section on the limits of Eruv use including the following three main points:

- Even within an Eruv, one may not enter non-Shabbat-compatible buildings (e.g. stores) on Shabbat.
- Even within an Eruv, one may not engage in non-Shabbat-compatible activities (e.g. gardening) on Shabbat.
- Even within an Eruv, one may not handle [Muktza](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muktzah) items (e.g. a hammer) on Shabbat.

See the link for more details and examples.

Comment: This answer would be more valuable if it cited a source.

Comment: @IsaacMoses added one.

Comment: @Naftali Can an item be carried that is not muktzah but is not needed on Shabbos? Examples might be an apple or a clean paper tissue.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot carry things for after shabbos - separate issur of hachana

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22700)

Comment: @mbloch It is as much a limit on "what you can carry" as muktza is.